# Is it possible to invoke methods of secured EJBs through message-driven beans?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, jaas, message-driven-bean

When a user logs in, I need to insert a message (the host name, just as an example) into the database. Since it is just a text message, injecting an EJB to a client (Servlets, JSP, JSF or something else) is quite unnecessary.

The client, in this case, it an authentication Filter through which I send the host name to a message-driven bean. With the help of a message-driven bean, the message is stored in a queue (not topic) which is then submitted to an EJB by injecting the EJB into this messaging bean.

The strategy mentioned here works fine. The problem arises when the EJB is enforced a security constraint. In which case, it throws an exception regarding the security.

The message-driven bean is as follows.

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/destination", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
})
public class UserStatusMessageBean implements MessageListener
{
    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext messageDrivenContext;
    @EJB
    private UserStatusBeanRemote userStatusBeanRemote;

    public UserStatusMessageBean() {}

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message)
    {
        TextMessage textMessage;

        try
        {
            if(message instanceof TextMessage)
            {
                textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                userStatusBeanRemote.addHost(textMessage.getText());
                //This EJB method causes the exception as given below.
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Message is of wrong type : " +message.getClass().getName());
            }
        }
        catch (JMSException e)
        {
            messageDrivenContext.setRollbackOnly();
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The stateless EJB has only one method until now which is responsible for inserting the message into the database using the JPA criteria API:

```
@Stateless
@DeclareRoles(value={"ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER"})
@RolesAllowed(value={"ROLE_ADMIN"})
public class UserStatusBean implements UserStatusBeanRemote
{
    @Override
    public void addHost(String hostName)
    {
         //Business logic to add the host name to the database.
    }
}
```

And the filter which authenticates the user is shown below (in case, it is needed to be reviewed).

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "SecurityCheck", urlPatterns = {"/jass/*"})
public final class SecurityCheck implements Filter
{
    @Resource(mappedName="jms/destinationFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    @Resource(mappedName="jms/destination")
    private Queue queue;
    @EJB
    private final UserBeanLocal userService=null;

    public SecurityCheck() {}

    private void sendJMSMessageToDestination(String message) throws JMSException
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        Session session = null;

        try
        {
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
            TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage();
            textMessage.setText(message);
            messageProducer.send(textMessage);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(session!=null){session.close();}
            if(connection!=null){connection.close();}
        }
    }

    private void doBeforeProcessing(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest=(HttpServletRequest)request;
        httpServletRequest.login(httpServletRequest.getParameter("userName"), httpServletRequest.getParameter("password"));
    }

    private void doAfterProcessing(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException, JMSException
    {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest=(HttpServletRequest)request;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse=(HttpServletResponse)response;
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();

        if(httpServletRequest.isUserInRole("ROLE_USER"))
        {
            sendJMSMessageToDestination(httpServletRequest.getLocalName());//Send a text message through a message-driven bean.
            String userName = httpServletRequest.getParameter("userName");
            UserTable userTable = userService.setLastLogin(userName);
            userTable.setPassword(null);
            sessionMap.put("userName", userTable!=null?userTable.getFirstName():"Unknown");
            sessionMap.put("user", userTable);

            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            httpServletResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("../user_side/Home.jsf");
        }
        else if(httpServletRequest.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN"))
        {
            sendJMSMessageToDestination(httpServletRequest.getLocalName());//Send a text message through a message-driven bean.

            String userName = httpServletRequest.getParameter("userName");
            UserTable userTable = userService.setLastLogin(userName);
            userTable.setPassword(null);
            sessionMap.put("adminName", userTable!=null?userTable.getFirstName():"Unknown");
            sessionMap.put("user", userTable);

            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            httpServletResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("../admin_side/Home.jsf");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        try
        {
            doBeforeProcessing(request, response);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse=(HttpServletResponse)response;
            //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error", "Incorrect user name and/or password. Access denied."));
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("../utility/Login.jsf");
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        try
        {
            doAfterProcessing(request, response);
        }
        catch (JMSException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(SecurityCheck.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    //The rest of this filter.
}
```

**The security applied here works fine elsewhere.** The annotation `@RolesAllowed(value={"ROLE_ADMIN"})` before the EJB `UserStatusBean` causes the following exception to be thrown.

```
WARNING: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB UserStatusBean, method: public void ejb.message.UserStatusBean.addHost(java.lang.String)
WARNING: javax.ejb.AccessLocalException: Client not authorized for this invocation
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:204)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
    at $Proxy366.addHost(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:239)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:150)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
    at ejb.message.__UserStatusBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.addHost(ejb/message/__UserStatusBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    at ejb.message._UserStatusBeanRemote_Wrapper.addHost(ejb/message/_UserStatusBeanRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at bean.message.UserStatusMessageBean.onMessage(UserStatusMessageBean.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainer.deliverMessage(MessageBeanContainer.java:1219)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanListenerImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBeanListenerImpl.java:81)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:171)
    at $Proxy406.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.OnMessageRunner.run(OnMessageRunner.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.work.OneWork.doWork(OneWork.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)

INFO:   javax.ejb.EJBAccessException
    at ejb.message._UserStatusBeanRemote_Wrapper.addHost(ejb/message/_UserStatusBeanRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at bean.message.UserStatusMessageBean.onMessage(UserStatusMessageBean.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainer.deliverMessage(MessageBeanContainer.java:1219)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanListenerImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBeanListenerImpl.java:81)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:171)
    at $Proxy406.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.OnMessageRunner.run(OnMessageRunner.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.work.OneWork.doWork(OneWork.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: java.rmi.AccessException: CORBA NO_PERMISSION 9998 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.NO_PERMISSION:   vmcid: 0x2000  minor code: 1806 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:264)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.wrapException(Util.java:695)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:150)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
    at ejb.message.__UserStatusBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.addHost(ejb/message/__UserStatusBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.NO_PERMISSION:   vmcid: 0x2000  minor code: 1806 completed: Maybe
Caused by: javax.ejb.AccessLocalException: Client not authorized for this invocation
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:204)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
    at $Proxy366.addHost(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:239)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:150)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
    at ejb.message.__UserStatusBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.addHost(ejb/message/__UserStatusBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    at ejb.message._UserStatusBeanRemote_Wrapper.addHost(ejb/message/_UserStatusBeanRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at bean.message.UserStatusMessageBean.onMessage(UserStatusMessageBean.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainer.deliverMessage(MessageBeanContainer.java:1219)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanListenerImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBeanListenerImpl.java:81)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:171)
    at $Proxy406.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.OnMessageRunner.run(OnMessageRunner.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.work.OneWork.doWork(OneWork.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
```

It works when this annotation `@RolesAllowed(value={"ROLE_ADMIN"})` before the EJB is removed.

Is it possible to invoke such methods through a message-driven bean?

I'm using GlassFish 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the @RunAs annotation for an MDB.

EJB specs says:

> The Bean Provider can use the RunAs metadata annotation or the Bean
>   Provider or Application Assembler can use the run-as deployment
>   descriptor element to define a run-as identity for an enterprise bean
>   in the deployment descriptor. **The run-as identity applies to the
>   enterprise bean as a whole**, that is, to all methods of the enterprise
>   bean’s business, home, and component interfaces, no-interface view,
>   and/or web service endpoint; **to the message listener methods of a
>   message-driven bean**; and to the timeout callback methods of an
>   enterprise bean; and all internal methods of the bean that they might
>   in turn call.

Caller principal propagation is not important in this case. It is not relevant who called the method and whether the identity is propagated, the run-as identity will be used instead and will be propagated further.

The run-as identity must be set-up correctly, though. Basically, if you use default principal to role mapping, you need to create a user e.g. `RunAsAdmin` and assign him the `ROLE_ADMIN` role. And then annotate your MDB with `@RunAs("RunAsAdmin")`.

Comment: The `@RunAs` annotation only worked (but not as expected), when I declared this list of roles - `ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN` in a file ream - `Configurations->server-config->Security->Realms->file` in the Assign Groups field in this file realm. The EJB method is invoked by any user authenticated with **any role** specified in the file realm. This should not happen. The EJB method should only be invoked by a user whose authority is `ROLE_ADMIN` - because of `@RolesAllowed(value={"ROLE_ADMIN"})`. The EJB method shouldn't be invoked, when MDB is annotated by `@RunAs(value="ROLE_USER")` but this happens

Comment: This [glassfish-ejb-jar.xml](http://pastebin.com/QttYYLFD) file of mine in the ejb module makes no sense at all (It makes no difference even though it is deleted).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `@RunAs` on the MDB, like this:

```
@MessageDriven(...)
@RunAs("ROLE_ADMIN")
public class UserStatusMessageBean implements MessageListener {
```

In general, though, EJB specification gives no guarantee that security context will pass through an MDB (see JSR-318 v. 3.1FR chapter 5.4.13):

> A caller principal may propagate into a message-driven bean’s message listener methods.  **Whether this occurs is a function of the specific message-listener interface and associated messaging provider**, but is not governed by this specification.

As to whether Glassfish handles this or not, perhaps someone else can help you.

Comment: Unfortunately this caused [this exception](http://pastebin.com/K8wdiRZe). Thanks for the effort.